# Release an application that uses Flutter under the GPL?

Tags: gpl, bsd, android

I want to write an Android application that uses [Flutter](https://github.com/flutter). Flutter has the "[BSD 3-Clause "New" or "Revised" License](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/LICENSE)". But I want to release my application as an application under the GPL. Would it be possible in this case or not? My application will only use Flutter framework, all the rest of the code I write myself.

Comment: You might want to read [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/4149/2870) over on law.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can release *your application* under the GPL.

You cannot alter copyright notices in Flutter, but you didn't ask about doing that.